# How to horizontally align content of ion-grid cell

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic4

When using ion-grid, how do I horizontally align the content of the cells to the left/right/center of the cell?

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="ion-align-self-left">
        left
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col class="ion-align-self-right">
        right
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

The content is always aligned to the left, I expect the text "right" to be aligned to the right of its own cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the `ion-text-end` css class as [documented here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#text-modification):

```
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="ion-text-start">
        left
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col class="ion-text-end">
        right
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
```

Renders as:

[image]

BTW: the flex option you were trying to use was the wrong class for that. In Ionic4 it's [start and end not left and right](https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#flex-properties).